# Unclear what asking - what next?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [Unassigned secondary IP stuck on AWS Linux EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/898886/unassigned-secondary-ip-stuck-on-aws-linux-ec2)

I realized after the fact that I didn't formulate it as a question exactly. Now I have added some clarification, but question hasn't been reviewed for some days. What can I do to make sure this questions lives up to standards and can be reopened?

Comment: The question was [reviewed for reopening](https://serverfault.com/review/reopen/360150) a week ago. I do not know why the community members voted as they did.

Comment: I would maybe edit it to put section, question, symptom, what you tried and result, as a edit will force another review

Comment: A note, the question is now open.